# Fragments BackStack. Fragments overlap even after pop.

Tags: android, android-fragments, overlapping, fragment-backstack

The problem is to manage properly back stack so the previous fragment is poped out (or deleted). The problem is in their overlapping..

The structure of program as follows:

- sliding menu with 3 fragments for each section: `CatalogFragment`, `NewsFragment`, `BlogFragment`;
- each fragment is a listView with items (parsed from JSON);
- on `CatalogFragment`'s item click I need to replace this `CatalogFragment` with `LessonsFragment`, which is list also.

*p.s. Items is in russian but I think you can understand*

[image]

This is how these fragments are added (dynamically):

```
    @Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
//        fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); //this also doesn't work

    switch (position+1) {
        case 1:
            //getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); // this doesnt work
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                    CatalogFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).addToBackStack("catalog").commit();

            break;
        case 2:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                    NewsFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).addToBackStack("news").commit();

            break;
        case 3:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                    BlogFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).addToBackStack("blog").commit();
            break;
    }
}
```

That's how I replace fragment with new one in `onCatalogFragmentInteraction` method from interface:

```
    /** Methods for interaction with list items*/
@Override
public void onCatalogFragmentInteraction(String id){
    //pop previous
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("catalog", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    //add new
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, LessonsFragment.newInstance());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("lessons");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

...and that works fine:

[image]

But when I move back to fragment from slididng menu fragments overlap.

[image]

I belive the problem lies in proper BackStack management but I can't figure out what I did wrong. Another suggestion is that I need to use `add/replace` somehow better in that case.

I have tried already deleting by name from stack. Maybe needed to delete them by ID?

P.S. Tell if some more code needed. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think your all fragments have transparent background or you did not set anything(so default is transparent). So the when you add/replace a fragment above another fragment the below fragment is visible to you. So try to set the background color for every fragment layout.

Comment: YES! Thanks! You made my day :D  

I've been suffering with it for second evening

Comment: This is not the correct solution, the overlapped Fragment will steal your input events. Thus causing other problems.

Comment: I had the same issue and I ended up trying to pop the back stack along with creating a new fragment over top using `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentInstance).addToBackStack( some_name ).commit();` but when I tried to just pop the back stack by name (and NOT creating a new fragment) it seemed to work like a charm for me.  PS, I was only going from a fragment back to the fragment that called it. But I figure I'd share my process.

Comment: @WenChao you can use `android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"` to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

I guess this is your xml of fragment, it may be other types of layout (Relative, Frame or other), try to put **background color** of your **parent layout** of xml of fragment. 
For example I put white color for background.

Comment: that's right, thanks. But **Chandrakanth** was first with answer

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass only an empty string as the fragment identifier in the addToBackStack.

And instead of

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("catalog", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE
```

just use

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: @Chrimson Tulip Nothing changed. I **DO** replace fragment with new one. But when I getting back from `Lessons` to `Catalog` they overlap. When I move vice versa, from `Catalog` to `Lessons` it **DOES** work. It must be some kind of Magic :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's perfect solution but this worked for me.

```
long back_pressed;
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "HERE WAS PRESSED BACK");
    int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    final Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_ANSWERS_FRAGMENT);
    if(null != fragment && fragment.isVisible()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "visible");
        showLeaveTest();
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "invisible");
        if (backStackEntryCount == 0) {
            if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) super.onBackPressed();
            else try {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.double_press, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            removeCurrentFragment(TAG_RESULT_FRAGMENT);
        }
    }
}

public void removeCurrentFragment(String fragmentTag)
{
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment currentFrag =  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
    String fragName = "NONE";

    if (currentFrag != null)
        fragName = currentFrag.getClass().getSimpleName();

    Log.d(TAG, "flag name " + fragName);

    if (currentFrag != null && currentFrag.isVisible())
        transaction.remove(currentFrag);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

So, I catch back button press in activity, and, after popping backstack, when fragment overlaps another fragment, this overlapping fragment is visible, so i just remove it with transaction.

Comment: Didn't test it but appreciate your interesting approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is yet another reason that this could happen:

- You are replacing all fragments into a view with id: `R.id.container`.
- Let's say you're pushing a Fragment `A` whose top-level layout has an id assigned to it e.g. `<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rootLayout">`
- Now any other fragment that you push on to `R.id.container` will overlap with Fragment `A`.

So just make sure that the root layout of the fragment that is being pushed does not have an id assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a background color to your every fragment's parent layout